# Setting up array key/value pairs and accessing

Tags: php

I have set up an array called $compData by importing data from MySql and pushing two separate arrays called $yearsArray and $salesArray into $compData. Before pushing these two arrays to $compData I have first set their ['name'] to 'Year' and 'Sales', respectively. The code for this is included below.

```
$sth = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM {$tableName} WHERE ID = 'ID_YEAR'");
$yearsArray = array();
$yearsArray['name'] = 'Year';
while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($sth)) {
    For ($n = 1; $n <= $CI_YEARS; $n++){
        $yearsArray['data'][] = $r["Year$n"];
    }
}

$sth = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM {$tableName} WHERE ID = 'IS_SALES'");
$salesArray = array();
$salesArray['name'] = 'Sales';
while($rr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    For ($n = 1; $n <= $CI_YEARS; $n++){
        $salesArray['data'][] = $rr["Year$n"];
    }
}

$compData = array();
array_push($compData,$yearsArray);  // 0
array_push($compData,$salesArray);  // 1
```

Now I want to access and echo the data in $compData by using the code below, but this doesn't work. I am not very comfortable with PHP and am wondering if I am not using the ['Year'] and ['Sales'] identifiers correctly. Any help is much appreciated.

```
foreach($compData['Year'] as $result) {
  echo $result, '<br>';
}

foreach($compData['Sales'] as $result) {
  echo $result, '<br>';
}
```

Comment: you've set `'Year'` as the _value_ of _key_ `'name'`. Now you try to use it as _key_ (of another array).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've set `'Year'` as the *value* of *key* `'name'`, but try to use it as *key* (of another array).

Now you have

```
echo $compData[0]['name']; // -> 'Year'
echo $compData[1]['name']; // -> 'Sales'
```

You probably want

```
 $compData = array();
 $compData['Year'] = $yearsArray; 
 $compData['Sales'] = $salesArray;
```

instead of the array_push..